# Maintain a Branch's 'independence' after merge with main branch

Tags: git, github

I code on a main branch (M) and add commits as I go. Last week I began planning a release a subset of new features, so I decided to split off a release branch (R) from an earlier commit on the main branch. Some bugs were subsequently found on the release branch, so the fixes in the release branch had to be merged back into the main branch.

```
M: ----------------*------------------
                   |
                   |
                   R:--------------------------------
```

I created a pull request and merged the release branch back into the main branch. However, now I found an additional bug in the release code. I want to fix the bug and create a bug-free release without the additional features in the main branch. But it looks like the release branch has become identical to the main branch as a result of the merge. How can I get my original release branch back?

And how can I manage this situation in the future so that the release branch doesn't change even after merging it's changes into the main branch?

Comment: What do you mean by "I created a pull request and merged the release branch back into the main branch." If you did exactly what you say here, then the main branch should have a merge commit and the release branch should be unchanged. On the other hand if you merged the main branch into the release branch, then the opposite is true: the main branch is unchanged and the release branch contains all the features from the main branch.

Comment: When you are bug fixing for a release, you should make the necessary commits onto the release branch, not the main branch. It sounds like you commited the bug fixes on the main branch on top of other features that don't need to go into the release, is that correct?

Comment: I mean literally that - I didn't think the release branch should change either as a result of the PR. And nope, I committed the bug fixes on the release branch.

Comment: It shouldn't if you did things correctly. Can you provide more detail? The important parts are what your current commit history looks like and where each branch points. Similar to your picture above, but show the merges.

Comment: Oh, coming to think of it, there was a merge conflict preventing the PR from being merged because of a few lines of an xml file. I wonder if fixing that conflict caused the main branch code to be added to the release branch.

Comment: One point of clarification: You write an `R` in the picture of your history. This indicates that you think the release branch starts at the first commit you made after creating the branch. This is an incorrect mental model of branching. In reality, the branch points at the **last** commit on the branch and contains **all** commits before it since the beginning of time.

Comment: "I wonder if fixing that conflict caused the main branch code to be added to the release branch." If the PR merged the main branch into the release branch, yes. If not, then no. Fixing conflicts has nothing to do with it. The way you set up the PR does.

Comment: OK then that's not it. I'll update the question with more details. Thanks for the clarification - I did have an incorrect mental model it looks like.

Answer (score 0):

A more accurate representation would be, from left (older commits) to right (newer commits):

```
x--x--x--x--x--x--x     (main)
          \
           r--r--r--r   (release)
```

If you have merged release to main:

```
x--x--x--x--x--x--x---M (main)
          \          /   
           r--r--r--r   (release)
```

If new bugs have been fixed in release, a new PR would allow you to merge them back to `main`.

```
x--x--x--x--x--x--x---M---M (main)
          \          /   /
           r--r--r--r --r   (release)
```

But in those merge cases, `release` should not be identical to `main`.